# Update values of a row based on id with sequelize gives 404 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, sequelize.js

I am currently working with nodeJS,expressJS and reactJS. I can currently access each data's id by clicking the edit button but I have issues actually updating the data everytime I click the button I get a 404 error in the console. I have looked through multiple questions and tutorials but none really helped with my confusion. I have a put route in my server.js to update the record based on the id:

```
app.put("update-list/:id", function (req, res, next) {
    Information.update({
        Name: req.body.name,
        Phone: req.body.phone,
        Email: req.body.email,
    }, { where: req.params.id }
    ).then(function (rowsUpdated) {
        res.json(rowsUpdated);
    }).catch(next)
});
```

Defined route in react:

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit}/>
```

How I am getting the api:

```
 let [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    phone: "",
    email: "",
  });
  let body = state;
  useEffect(()=>{
    handleSubmit(props);
  })
  function handleSubmit(props) {
    const id=props.match.id
    axios({
      method: "put",
      url: "http://localhost:5000/update-list/"+id,
      data: body,
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

    console.log(state);
  }
```

On change function:

```
function handleChange(e, field) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = e.target.value;
    setState({
        ...state,
        [field]: e.target.value,
    });
}
```

The button click is calling the `handleChange()` function and the form is calling `handleSubmit()`.
Am I missing something or is this completely the wrong way to do it? Let me know if you need any more details!

Comment: `{where:req.params.id}` is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.put("/update-list/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  db.Information.update({
    Name: req.body.name,
    Phone: req.body.phone,
    Email: req.body.email,
  }, { where: { id: req.params.id } } // This is fixed
  ).then(function (rowsUpdated) {
    res.json(rowsUpdated);
  }).catch(next)
});
```

React.js Project: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize-react.js-client/tree/stack-66271022

API Project: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize/tree/stack-66271022